# scp - files getting different sizes in destination folder

Tags: server, ssh, disk-usage, scp

While using scp, the total file size was noticed to be 0.1G less in the destination folder and, a few files were noticed to be larger in size in the destination folder. What could have caused this?

The source directory individual as well as total sizes as follows:

`du -h *`:

```
0   acnoltcustmktikprd1.vmsd
4.0K    acnoltcustmktikprd1.vmx
4.0K    acnoltcustmktikprd1.vmxf
5.1G    mikrotiktest-flat.vmdk
12K mikrotiktest.nvram
4.0K    mikrotiktest.vmdk
0   mikrotiktest.vmsd
4.0K    mikrotiktest.vmxf
224K    vmware-1.log
168K    vmware-2.log
420K    vmware-3.log
336K    vmware-4.log
252K    vmware-5.log
252K    vmware-6.log
256K    vmware.log
```

`du -csh .`

```
5.1G    .
5.1G    total
```

The destination directory individual as well as total sizes are as follows:

`du -h *`:

```
0   acnoltcustmktikprd1.vmsd
8.0K    acnoltcustmktikprd1.vmx
0   acnoltcustmktikprd1.vmxf
5.0G    mikrotiktest-flat.vmdk
1.0M    mikrotiktest.nvram
0   mikrotiktest.vmdk
0   mikrotiktest.vmsd
0   mikrotiktest.vmxf
1.0M    vmware-1.log
1.0M    vmware-2.log
1.0M    vmware-3.log
1.0M    vmware-4.log
1.0M    vmware-5.log
1.0M    vmware-6.log
1.0M    vmware.log
```

`du -csh .`

```
5.0G    .
5.0G    total
```

Regarding the filesystems: The Source system was on Ubuntu 12.04/ext4 and the  destination sysytem was VMware vSphere VMFS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the remote and local filesystems.

Comment: @terdon : Kindly  check the update.

Comment: Yup, then NewUser gave you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has no matter with `scp`. This is an issue of file system and the used block size.

In simple word and as an example if you use a block size of 512 KB and you have a file 2.5MB size then this file will reserve 5 blocks.
Here when filesystem reads the size it will calculate 5*512KB=2.5MB

Now if you have the block size of  1MB then the same file of 2.5MB in size will reserve 3 blocks.
Here when filesystem reads the size it will calculate 3*1MB=3MB

read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)) and [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/filesystems.html) for more information

**Another possible reason**

If the two systems have the same block size, then this may be caused by the starting sector of files.

I.e, what I mean that a block indeed in FIlesystem is a collection of many sectors. Those sectors (4 by default I think) consist the Data block.

so in case suppose

in system A the files starts from sector 1 of block 0 while in system B it start from sector 0 of block 0. then this leads to different in size since File in system A will reserve more sectors and thus more blocks and though more size

Comment: Note that you can use `du -b` to get the real size, not disk size.